# How to insert data into table with only two decimal places using python?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to insert data into a database using python and SQL queries.
I want to insert data up to 2 decimal places only. So what should I do?

My code:

```
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO DHT_sensor VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",(i,temperature,humidity))
```

Comment: Do you have any Python code?

Comment: Are you saying that i,temperature and humidity can be more than 2 decimal places but you want to round/truncate before inserting?

Comment: Why not insert the data unmodified, and then round it when displaying it to the user? Showing only two decimal places is typically a *presentation* requirement, not a data storage one. What happens when the requirement changes to 4 decimal places? Your historical data is ruined.

Answer (score 0):

```
i,temperature,humidity = 12.2345, 14.5653442, 4346.345363

q = "INSERT INTO DHT_sensor VALUES (%.2f,%.2f,%.2f)"%(i,temperature,humidity)

print(q)
#INSERT INTO DHT_sensor VALUES (12.23,14.57,4346.35)

mycursor.execute(q)
```